# How to List files from user Google Drive in my android application?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

I'm having trouble fetching the user's Google Drive files to display them in my Android application. I've been trying for about 5 days now, and I've read a lot of documentation before asking for help here, but I just can't figure out how to get the authentication to fetch user data from Drive.

I've tried various methods, one of which involved creating an application on Google Cloud, enabling the Google Drive API, generating the credentials.json file in OAuth, and adding it to my project, but it didn't work.

I also attempted the quickstart available on the website https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/java?hl=pt-br, but it doesn't seem to work for Android applications.

I followed the documentation provided on this page without success: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java

According to the documentation above, it should be as simple as:

```
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("/path/to/credentials.json"));
credentials.refreshIfExpired();
AccessToken token = credentials.getAccessToken();
```

Also tried this example without success: https://github.com/googleworkspace/android-samples/tree/master/drive/deprecation

However, I'm getting numerous errors that I honestly can't understand.

Do I need to have a backend server to make these requests?

My application is already connecting to Firebase with Google authentication; all I want is to fetch the list of files from the Drive.

Sorry for being such a noob but I'm just starting on android development.

I appreciate the help.

I also attempted the quickstart available on the website https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/java?hl=pt-br, but it doesn't seem to work for Android applications.

I followed the documentation provided on this page without success: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java

Also tried this example without success: https://github.com/googleworkspace/android-samples/tree/master/drive/deprecation

I need my android app, after the user logged in, list his google drive files.

Here's my mainActivity.java, only Firebase login is working.

```
package com.example.app;

import static java.lang.System.in;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;


import com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;

import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.ValueRange;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Nothing actually happens here.  This is only here so I know it installed on the phone for
 * to test with.  Normally there won't be one at all.
 */

public class mainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";
    
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Widget Sheet";

    private static File folder;

    private static final List<String> SCOPES =
            Collections.singletonList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS_READONLY);


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Abre a tela de início com as instruções
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.inicio);

        try {
              isStoragePermissionGranted();

              folder = getDir("tokens", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

              listFiles();
              
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        // Iniciar o processo de login com Firebase
        FirebaseLoginHelper.startFirebaseLogin(this);
    }

    public static void listFiles() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        final String spreadsheetId = "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms";
        final String range = "Class Data!A2:E";
        Sheets service =
                new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                        .build();
        ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
                .get(spreadsheetId, range)
                .execute();
        List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
        if (values == null || values.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No data found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Name, Major");
            for (List row : values) {
                // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
                System.out.printf("%s, %s\n", row.get(0), row.get(4));
            }
        }
    }

    public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.println(Log.DEBUG, "DEB","Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {
                Log.println(Log.DEBUG, "DEB","Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                        android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.println(Log.DEBUG, "DEB","Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }
    }

    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT)
            throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = mainActivity.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));



        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(folder))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();

        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }

    // Tratar o resultado do login usando Firebase
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        FirebaseLoginHelper.handleLoginResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        
    }

    // Tratar a resposta da solicitação de permissão para o Google Drive
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        Log.w("Drive","Solicitado");
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Error presented:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.mainActivity}:
> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: 1. Please show the code that you have tried (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 2. What you are expecting to happen if the code is right 3. What you are actually getting (show the error output as much as possible)

Comment: @RadianceWeiQiOng added my mainActivity code do the question. I only need to show user file list. After I get the data I will be able to deal with showing wherever I want. My problem is all auth, api and oauth.

Comment: You should add the full stack trace (with the line numbers) so that we can tell where the problem originated. Anyway it is likely that you are making network calls on the main thread. You should do it in another thread using ExecutorService or similar (https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService). You can search android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException for more info (but note that old answers would recommend old way of using another thread e.g. AsyncTask)